# can we call service methods from spring boot rest api app in apache kafka consumer?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am working on kafka and spring boot application. I am writing a file to drive using java File api. File data is in database. I have repository and service layer in application. If file size is greater than 50MB then I am calling kafka producer and pass a List of Id's as value. Can I call Service methods to pull data In my kafka Consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "If file size is greater than 50MB then I am calling kafka producer and pass a List of Id's as value" ? All you need to do only write a Kafka producer to send data to Kafka cluster and a Kafka consumer to pull records from Kafka cluster then write to file in drive.

Because you use Spring Boot for your project you can use query methods in your repository class to pull data from database, pass through your service layer then Kafka producer will do its job. In your Kafka consumer you just need to consume records by using @KafkaListener annotation of Spring Kafka. So many sample codes you can find by few Google search.

Comment: direct download if file size is less than 50 MB, Otherwise i am producing a job and putting it in kafka queue. I figured it out. I didn't knew about spring boot support for kafka. Now I have implemented it. Thank you.